# WCF Service Authorization via Username and Password

Tags: wcf, passwords, authorization, asp.net-3.5

Edited 3.9.2011 to add one more related question

Hello,

I'm very new to WCF and doing a crash course right now.

Can I please have a second set of eyes review my plans?

Here are the (planned) details:

The goal is to make an internet-accessible WCF service that uses a username and password for authorization with the credentials and message content protected in transit by SSL.

A WCF SOAP Service

- Binding: wsHttpBinding
- Auth: UsernameAuthentication (custom)
- Security Mode: Transport

Will these items live gracefully together? I was not sure if I needed to change the security mode to "TransportWithMessageCredential".

A related question: I'm trying to get identity information, similar to using HttpContext.Current.User. Is this how I can do it?

```
IIdentity myIdentity = 
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity;
```

Please let me know if I need to change my binding, auth, or security mode.

Thanks so much!

Edit - Additional Question: When first conceived, the plan was to have the consumer send the username and password as part of the message. Credentials would be secured by SSL. then, in the respective service method's code, I'd eval if they have access or not and stop them. This seems like a simpler method of implementing authorization, but are there any downsides I need to know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those settings should be fine - wsHttpBinding supports transport security with username/password credentials.

As for the identity: in your service-side code, you can inspect the `ServiceSecurityContext` and find the identity of the caller on that:

```
ServiceSecurityContext secCtx = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
var identity = secCtx.PrimaryIdentity;
```

Comment: One more question: Can I do uname and password auth and turn off not use transport security, just for proof-of-concept / testing purposes? I'd like to use Cassini to test instead of making a cert, etc just to test the uname / password functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @D-Sect: no, I don't think so. Since you're sending uname/pwd along with the message, the transport needs to be secured.

Comment: To clarify, this would be for dev purposes only. Are you saying if I use UsernameAuthentication, then it will not operate without transport security? Also - please see the edit which asked a related question. Thanks!

Comment: @D-Sect: yes, that would be my understanding - if you don't have any transport security, you cannot use username/pwd authentication with wsHttpBinding.